# Metro bundler disconnects automatically on android after build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cross-platform, metro-bundler

When I create build in android using android studio or terminal, my metro bundler is disconnected automatically. I cannot debug using wire. I have to connect wirelessly which is very slow.

Is there any way so that the bundler remains connected after build?

I tried many things but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure your Android device and your machine are on the same network.
Hope it helps!

Comment: It worked somehow. Although I tried this before. Thanks anyway.